# Producing and streaming to a local Network

Tags: video, streaming, live, broadcasting, live-performance

i'm facing the challenge of creating a "TV-Show". To understand why i do this i will explain it in detail, but summarize it in the end, for the ones who just want to know what my problem is.

LONG VERSION:
At my school we have a something call a 'graduation prank'. When every a class is leaving the school at the end of a year, they plan something where they do something funny. This is different every year.
This year we are going to leave the school. Your idea is it to produce a "TV-Show". We want to stream it over your pretty fast local network (we have wifi in the wholes school connection [so the speed intern will not be a problem i think]). We will pre-produce some sketchs and short clips but also want to do live things.

PROBLEM:
I need hardware and software to produce and stream a videostream to a local network. I search the web a lot and came up with a few ideas.
The main part is a "BlackMagic ATEM Television Switch". It will switch our HDMI/SDI cameras (we have them). The ATEM needs to be bought. To get the video into a PC (i think of two MacBook Pro Retina late 2014 with nVidea [we have them too])  i would like to use the "BlackMagic Design UltraStudio Mini Recorder".
Hardware ok. But what software could i use? Wirecast, Adobe Flash thingi?! I downloaded a few but are they able to stream to a local network? I only saw things like Twitch and Youtube (thins wont work, we have no good up/down-link, only intern a lot of speed).

So: Is here someone who knows a program with what i can stream to a local network. Use capterd video data and play pre-made clips? Maybe even some Chroma-Keying?
And: How does my Hardware setup sounds to you?

Comment: From the tags on your question, I gather you want the show to be live, being viewed by the audience    while cameras are rolling.  (viewing on TVs?  Over the same wifi network on smartphones and laptops?)  I started reading thinking you were asking about setting up a video server so everyone in your school could watch it, after you had it already made and encoded.  But since that's not what you're asking, I don't have anything more to add, except that you might have wifi bandwidth issues if everyone's streaming the result over the same network you're using to carry high-datarate live capture.